# Ajax Control Toolkit, Visual Studio 2010, error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to develop an Ajax based website. where is installed ajax control toolkit on visual studio 2010. I created a page.

Here is the code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test2.aspx.cs" Inherits="QMSStandard.test2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
    </asp:CalendarExtender>
</div>
</form>
```

when I run this page its shows error

> Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure
>   the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an
>   ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in
>   AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

Kindly suggest how can i use these controls.

Comment: you should put `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager>` instead of `<asp:ScriptManager>`

Answer (score 1):

first remove `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>` and then drag and drop `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager>` from Ajax Toolbox control

Comment: kindly suggest me something. i am facing a problem when i add AjaxControltoolkit to my visual studio. it shows its all control under the newly defined tab but when i close Visual Studio and restart it, all ajax control disappeared. i am stuck.